# Pronunciation of Los Angeles with /g/ and not /dʒ/, /lɒs'æŋgələs/ as opposed to /lɒs'ændʒələs/

Tags: pronunciation

I remember reading in an early Michael Connelly novel from the late nineties a remark about how one of the characters pronounced Los Angeles with a /g/ sound, making it /lɒs'æŋgələs/.

So far as I remember, the character was a woman in her sixties, so she would have been born in the thirties.  Such a pronunciation is given as less common than /lɒs'ændʒələs/ by J.C Wells in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary.  Now apart from this fictitious character, I've never heard anyone say Los Angeles like that.

Is this way of pronouncing it still extant?  If yes, do age or other considerations account for it?

Comment: I'm a little torn, because this question is interesting, but maybe falls down in the "shows research" department. A quick Google search for "pronounce los angeles hard g" comes up with an [LA Times article](https://www.latimes.com/local/la-xpm-2011-jun-26-la-me-0626-then-20110626-story.html), a [city-data](http://www.city-data.com/forum/los-angeles/1314224-lat-article-history-evolving-pronunciation-los.html) thread, a [quora](https://www.quora.com/When-did-people-switch-from-pronouncing-Los-Angeles-with-a-hard-g-to-pronouncing-it-with-a-soft-g) question, ... (1/2)

Comment: ...a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LosAngeles/comments/73hljl/did_los_angeles_used_to_be_pronounced_as_los/) thread, and a couple of [Straight](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=396180) [Dope](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=261921) threads. (2/2)

Comment: Thanks for the info!  The LA Times article I can't access from Europe but the other tips are quite interesting and point to the conclusion that the /g/ pronunciation has died out entirely.

Comment: The City of Los Angeles was named after *angels* (with /dʒ/) and not *angles* (with /g/). And neither of these consonants is that close to the Spanish.

Comment: Related: [Should “Los Angeles” rhyme with “cheese” or “less”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419331)